# Getting exceptions from reccurent events in Google Calenader API v3

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been developing an application to download whole calendars from all users in domain and save them in ICS format. The app is written in Java. I get access using 2L OAuth. So far I'm able to get most of calendar's data, excluding exceptions from recurrent events. Google API docs say that every recurrent event should contain a list of recurrence, including EXRULEs. But when I call the API I got only recurrent rule without exception.
It there any way to get these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You get the exceptions as regular item and

```
event.getOriginalEvent()
```

will return reference to reccuring event.